# Generate leading values in hive table

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I have two tables like below cust_msg & cust_audit.

```
cust_msg
+-----------+----------+------------+----------+                                        
|cust_id    |first_name|progress    |process_dt|
+-----------+----------+------------+----------+
|106674     |Charley   |Initiate    |20210202  |
|106674     |Charley   |Review      |20210203  |
|106674     |Charley   |Realign     |20210204  |
|106674     |Charley   |Approved    |20210211  |
|106674     |Charley   |Installation|20210216  |
|106674     |Charley   |Survey      |20210323  |
+-----------+----------+------------+----------+


cust_audit
+-----------+----------+----------------------------+----------+                                        
|cust_id    |agent_id  |adt_log                     |process_dt|
+-----------+----------+----------------------------+----------+
|106674     |602       |Promotional Offer sent      |20210112  |
|106674     |602       |Click Open Promo            |20210113  |
|106674     |100       |Promo Inquiry               |20210114  |
|106674     |100       |Cust Waiting                |20210118  |
|106674     |100       |Customer Application        |20210119  |
|106674     |602       |Appl Approved               |20210122  |
|106674     |602       |Initiate Appl               |20210201  |
|106674     |602       |Sale Initiated              |20210202  |
|106674     |602       |sale Rv Pending             |20210203  |
|106674     |602       |sales-cust Realign          |20210203  |
|106674     |602       |cust in aggrement           |20210204  |
|106674     |602       |Sales Dep Approve           |20210208  |
|106674     |602       |mgt Approved                |20210211  |
|106674     |602       |Installation pending        |20210216  |
|106674     |602       |Cust Survey                 |20210323  |
+-----------+----------+----------------------------+----------+
```

I need to build another table `cust_del_detail` as below in which the
`progress` should be `Initiate` until `process_dt = 20210202` as `progress` in table `cust_msg` is `Initiate` on 20210202,
`progress` should be `Review` on `20210203` &
`progress` should be `Realign` from `20210204` to `20210208` &
and similarly `Approved` on `20210211` &
`Installation` on `20210216` &
`Survey` on `20210323`

```
cust_del_detail
+-----------+--------------+----------+---------------------------+---------------+----------+                                        
|cust_id    |first_name    |agent_id  |adt_log                    |progress       |process_dt|
+-----------+--------------+----------+---------------------------+---------------+----------+
|106674     |Charley       |602       |Promotional Offer sent     |Initiate       |20210112  |
|106674     |Charley       |602       |Click Open Promo           |Initiate       |20210113  |
|106674     |Charley       |100       |Promo Inquiry              |Initiate       |20210114  |
|106674     |Charley       |100       |Cust Waiting               |Initiate       |20210118  |
|106674     |Charley       |100       |Customer Application       |Initiate       |20210119  |
|106674     |Charley       |602       |Appl Approved              |Initiate       |20210122  |
|106674     |Charley       |602       |Initiate Appl              |Initiate       |20210201  |
|106674     |Charley       |602       |Sale Initiated             |Initiate       |20210202  |
|106674     |Charley       |602       |sale Rv Pending            |Review         |20210203  |
|106674     |Charley       |602       |sales-cust Realign         |Review         |20210203  |
|106674     |Charley       |602       |cust in aggrement          |Realign        |20210204  |
|106674     |Charley       |602       |Sales Dep Approve          |Realign        |20210208  |
|106674     |Charley       |602       |mgt Approved               |Approved       |20210211  |
|106674     |Charley       |602       |Installation pending       |Installation   |20210216  |
|106674     |Charley       |602       |Cust Survey                |Survey         |20210323  |
+-----------+--------------+----------+---------------------------+---------------+----------+
```

I tried using lead window function in hive but unable to achieve it.
What is the best way to achieve this in Hive or Pyspark?

Comment: Logic little confusing. Why `Realign` will be from 20210204 to 20210208? I am trying to understand why some `progress` should be tied to `adt_log`. You can say based on date but how ? Can you give more details? If it helps, probably you can join both and add a join condition like `process_dt` between `audit_log.process_dt`

Comment: `Realign` Came in for the process_dt  20210204 to 20210208 because, in the table `cust_msg`  `Realign` came in on `20210204` until `20210211`

Yes I need to join the tables  `cust_audit` and `cust_msg`  have the fields `first_name` and `progress` in the   `cust_audit`  data. The `progress` in the resultant table should be based on `process_dt` in both the tables   `cust_audit` and `cust_msg`

In the table `cust_msg` the `progress`  `Initiate` came on `20210202`. So until the process_dt `20210202` in `cust_audit` I want to show `Initiate` = progress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lead` and do a join:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

cust_del_detail = cust_msg.withColumn(
    'lead_dt', 
    F.lead('process_dt').over(Window.partitionBy('cust_id').orderBy('process_dt'))
).alias('cust_msg').join(
    cust_audit.alias('cust_audit'), 
    F.expr('''
        (progress != "Initiate" 
         and (cust_audit.process_dt < cust_msg.lead_dt or cust_msg.lead_dt is null) 
         and (cust_audit.process_dt >= cust_msg.process_dt)
        ) 
        or 
        (progress = "Initiate" 
         and (cust_audit.process_dt <= cust_msg.process_dt)
        )
    '''),
    'right'
).selectExpr(
    'cust_msg.cust_id', 
    'cust_msg.first_name', 
    'cust_audit.agent_id', 
    'cust_audit.adt_log', 
    'cust_msg.progress', 
    'cust_audit.process_dt'
)
```

Result:

```
cust_del_detail.show(truncate=False)
+-------+----------+--------+----------------------+------------+----------+
|cust_id|first_name|agent_id|adt_log               |progress    |process_dt|
+-------+----------+--------+----------------------+------------+----------+
|106674 |Charley   |602     |Promotional Offer sent|Initiate    |20210112  |
|106674 |Charley   |602     |Click Open Promo      |Initiate    |20210113  |
|106674 |Charley   |100     |Promo Inquiry         |Initiate    |20210114  |
|106674 |Charley   |100     |Cust Waiting          |Initiate    |20210118  |
|106674 |Charley   |100     |Customer Application  |Initiate    |20210119  |
|106674 |Charley   |602     |Appl Approved         |Initiate    |20210122  |
|106674 |Charley   |602     |Initiate Appl         |Initiate    |20210201  |
|106674 |Charley   |602     |Sale Initiated        |Initiate    |20210202  |
|106674 |Charley   |602     |sale Rv Pending       |Review      |20210203  |
|106674 |Charley   |602     |sales-cust Realign    |Review      |20210203  |
|106674 |Charley   |602     |cust in aggrement     |Realign     |20210204  |
|106674 |Charley   |602     |Sales Dep Approve     |Realign     |20210208  |
|106674 |Charley   |602     |mgt Approved          |Approved    |20210211  |
|106674 |Charley   |602     |Installation pending  |Installation|20210216  |
|106674 |Charley   |602     |Cust Survey           |Survey      |20210323  |
+-------+----------+--------+----------------------+------------+----------+
```